# App's application created but main activity is not create

Tags: android, android-activity, launcher

My app is a Launcher.

start an app on launcher. 
when my launcher is in background, from logcat I can see that Application is created but the main activity is not created.

```
public class LauncherApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        super.onCreate();
        ......
        Log.d("TAG", "onCreated");
    }
}

public class MyLauncher extends Activity {
    .....
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:name="com.launcher.LauncherApplication"
    android:label="@string/application_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:process="android.process.acore" 
android:largeHeap="true"
    android:persistent="true" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.launcher.MyLauncher"
          android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|keyboardHidden|keyboard|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|navigation|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:persistent="true" 
        android:allowBackup="true" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 ......
 </Application>
```

MyLauncher is the main activity.

My question is: 
when log prints "onCreated", that means my launcher is killed bo OS in background and LauncherApplication is restarted ?

Comment: post your manifest.xml file

Comment: ok, manifest.xml is posted